# GoLang FanIn function not working

Tags: concurrency, go

So I'm trying to write a webcrawler using Rob Pike's fanin function.

This is my code -

```
package main
import (
    "net/http"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
)


func main() {
   fanIn(getDuckDuckGo("food"), getGitHub("defunkt"))

}

type DuckDuckGoResponse struct {
    RelatedTopics []struct {
        Result string `json:"Result"`
        FirstUrl string `json:"FirstURL"`
        Text string `json:"Text"`
    } `json:"RelatedTopics"`
}

type GitHubResponse struct {
    Login string `json:"login"`
    Email string `json:"email"`
    Name string `json:"name"`
}

func fanIn(input1 <-chan DuckDuckGoResponse, input2 <-chan GitHubResponse) <-chan string {
    c := make(chan string)
    go func() {
        for {
            select {
            case s := <-input1:
                fmt.Println(s)
            case s := <-input2:
                fmt.Println(s)
            }
        }
    }()
    return c
}


func getDuckDuckGo(k string) <-chan DuckDuckGoResponse {
    resp, err := http.Get("http://api.duckduckgo.com/?q=" + k + "&format=json&pretty=1")
    if err != nil {
        return nil
    }
    c := make(chan DuckDuckGoResponse)
    var duckDuckParsed DuckDuckGoResponse
    jsonDataFromHttp, jsonErr := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)

    if jsonErr != nil {
        fmt.Println("Json error!")
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()


    if err:= json.Unmarshal(jsonDataFromHttp, &duckDuckParsed); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    return c
}

func getGitHub(k string) <-chan GitHubResponse {
    resp, err := http.Get("https://api.github.com/users/?q=" + k)
    if err != nil {
        return nil
    }
    c := make(chan GitHubResponse)

    var githubParsed GitHubResponse
    jsonDataFromHttp, jsonErr := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)

    if jsonErr != nil {
        fmt.Println("Json error!")
    }

    defer resp.Body.Close()

    if err:= json.Unmarshal(jsonDataFromHttp, &githubParsed); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    return c
}
```

I run this program, and nothing prints.

Why?

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean? I thought by calling the fan in function, something would print everytime one of my sub channels gave back a value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first glance, the `fanIn` function returns a channel that is not being read from in your main loop.  So yes, you are invoking the `fanIn` function which returns a channel, but there is nothing reading off of that channel.  For a channel to be useful there needs to be a consumer *consuming* from the channel while on the other end there needs to be a producer *producing* on that channel.  In other words, sending on a channel can't make progress unless someone on the other end is ready to receive on it.

Next, your `getGitHub` and `getDuckDuckGo` return channels, but they don't actually send anything on those channels that they return.  Also, what you really need is a way to invoke those functions, have them return a channel and still execute your work.  You need to use additional goroutines in order be able to have the http.Get calls do their work.

Lastly, your fanIn function also creates a channel and returns it, however it doesn't actually "fan-in" the results from input1 or input2.  Since the fanIn returns a channel of type string, you'll need to write a string into them which could be a field off of `DuckDuckGoResponse` and `GitHubResponse`.

I urge you too look at this streamlined example of what you are trying to accomplish: https://talks.golang.org/2012/go-docs/faninboring.go

Last observation you are checking that `jsonErr != nil` and printing it out but you probably want to return nil as well to prevent the code from continuing on.

I hope this gives you just enough insight to get your code working.  Good luck!

Comment: what do you mean? I thought that the fan in function would just run the printlns everytime channels sent back a value?

Comment: Please see this article: https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#channels  Specifically to quote the article: `Receivers always block until there is data to receive. If the channel is unbuffered, the sender blocks until the receiver has received the value.`